# Integrating javascript files in wordpress custom theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I know that there already are several topics with this matter but none of them seem to resolve my problem.

I want to link in a custom WordPress theme that I am creating several JavaScript files. I've tried a lot of possible ways and none of them seem to work for me.

To skip all the ways I've already tried to add the files please tell me for example how can I add the file "prettyPhoto.js" in order to work in my custom theme.

Thank you,
Andi

Comment: Add this file your "wp-content/theme/mytheme" directory , and make the path of this file to your header.php file which is present in "wp-content/theme/mytheme/header.php" with complete name example: <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo blog_info('template_url')."/prettyPhoto.js" ?>"></script>

Comment: I am sorry but what you wrote here does not work, after I've added the line you told me the blog does not display in the browser anymore

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to use `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script`. Using these will instruct WordPress to load your script after any dependent scripts.

So say your `prettyPhoto.js` file is in `mytheme/js`. In `functions.php`, add something like:

```
<?php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_load_scripts');
function mytheme_load_scripts() {
  // this only registers the script with WordPress
  wp_register_script('prettyPhoto', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/prettyPhoto.js');
  // this actually loads the script in `wp_head`
  wp_enqueue_script('prettyPhoto');
}
?>
```

If `prettyPhoto.js` is dependent on jQuery or something, then you specify this in `wp_register_script`. Doing the below will tell WordPress to ensure jQuery is loaded before your script is loaded.

```
<?php
wp_register_script('prettyPhoto', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/prettyPhoto.js', array('jquery'));
?>
```

See [wp_register_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) in the codex for more.

[This article](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/) will probably help, too.

Comment: After adding the code above I receive an error that says that I should correct some error in the file plugin.php which I do not have :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess it didn't work for You, because You probably forgot about placing [wp_head()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head)

> immediately before  tag in a theme template (ex. header.php,
>   index.php)

or about placing [wp_footer()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer)

> immediately before  tag in a theme template (ex. footer.php,
>   index.php).

Take some time and make yourself familiar with the [Theme Development Checklist](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development_Checklist).

It's hard to guess without seeing the template and without knowing what You've tried already,
but what You need is the [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function (in `functions.php`) together with wp_head() and|or wp_footer() (in the template).

1. Make sure, there is `wp_head()` right before `</head>` in the template.
2. Make sure, there is `wp_footer()` right before `</body>` in the template.
3. Place the following code in `functions.php`:

   ```
   function my_theme_add_javascript() {
       wp_enqueue_script(
           'pretty-photo',
           get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/prettyPhoto.js',
           array('jquery')
       );
   }
   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_add_javascript');
   ```

Comment: Thank you for replying but unfortunately for some unknown reason the code you've sent me is not working. I am 100% sure that there are some problems in my php files but I really do not know how to figure it out :(